# How can I include an ssl key passphrase with git push ionic master

Tags: ionic-framework

I'd like to get ionic pro into my normal CI/CD pipeline. So it seems that when I commit code, I should be able to have my server call "git push ionic master". But this will be unattended and the server won't be able to respond to the prompt "Enter passphrase for key '/u/.ssh/id_rsa':".

Is there a way I can include the passphrase as an argument to the git push command? Or is there another way to do this?

Thanks.